# .htaccess unblock bad redirect on get request

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

Here I am facing a redirection problem when I make a GET request on my new form.

On an existing hosting, I added a domain to add some forms.

My tree is:
- www
- apps.monsite.com
- b3web
- .htaccess

I do not put you, but here are the elements that concern my problem.

here is the content of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/b3web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b3web/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.fr$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ b3web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ b3web/index.php [L]
```

When I access my new form with the url type: http://apps.mysite.com/monform.php, it appears correctly. If I add "? Uuid = jlerjlrjklr" I get the following redirection error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /b3web/apps.monsite.com/bonsav.php&uuid=euiorprt was not found on this server.
```

Which is "normal" because the form is not in the "b3web" directory, and I do not understand why it is doing this redirection. How can I block this redirection without breaking the rest of the sites?

Thanks in advance

Vincent

Comment: .htaccess did nothing of this redirection, the redirection might be from the php script. so you want to block the redirection where there is `uuid` parameter?

Comment: I have no redirection in my php script, and works well on my local computer. I don't understand why my script redirect to a bad folder when I add the uuid parameter

Comment: is the same problem happened if using incognito mode? the permanent redirect will cache by browser

Comment: I do not have the problem anymore. Surely a browser cache problem. Thank you